# Nopcommerce 3.4 - javascript code inside _CreateOrUpdateAddress.cshtml in Admin

Tags: javascript, nopcommerce, editorformodel

I'm trying to find where I can edit some javascript code that gets injected into a Html.EditorFor statement inside the  _CreateOrUpdateAddress.cshtml in Presentation > Nop.Admin > Views > Customer.

The javascript code basically fills the StateProvince dropdown select when an option is selected in the Country dropdown select.

This is the code inside _CreateOrUpdateAddress.cshtml:

```
@model CustomerAddressModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, "Address")
```

and this is the generated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Address_CountryId").change(function() {
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    var ddlStates = $("#Address_StateProvinceId");
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Admin/Country/GetStatesByCountryId",
        data: { "countryId": selectedItem, "addEmptyStateIfRequired": "true" },
        success: function(data) {
            ddlStates.html('');
            $.each(data, function(id, option) {
            ddlStates.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
        });
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
<input id="Address_Id" type="hidden" value="0" name="Address.Id" data-val-required="'Id' must not be empty." data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_FirstNameEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.FirstNameEnabled" data-val-required="'First Name Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_FirstNameRequired" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.FirstNameRequired" data-val-required="'First Name Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_LastNameEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.LastNameEnabled" data-val-required="'Last Name Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_LastNameRequired" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.LastNameRequired" data-val-required="'Last Name Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_EmailEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.EmailEnabled" data-val-required="'Email Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_EmailRequired" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.EmailRequired" data-val-required="'Email Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_CompanyEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.CompanyEnabled" data-val-required="'Company Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_CompanyRequired" type="hidden" value="False" name="Address.CompanyRequired" data-val-required="'Company Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_CountryEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.CountryEnabled" data-val-required="'Country Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_StateProvinceEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.StateProvinceEnabled" data-val-required="'State Province Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_CityEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.CityEnabled" data-val-required="'City Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_CityRequired" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.CityRequired" data-val-required="'City Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_StreetAddressEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.StreetAddressEnabled" data-val-required="'Street Address Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_StreetAddressRequired" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.StreetAddressRequired" data-val-required="'Street Address Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_StreetAddress2Enabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.StreetAddress2Enabled" data-val-required="'Street Address2 Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_StreetAddress2Required" type="hidden" value="False" name="Address.StreetAddress2Required" data-val-required="'Street Address2 Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_ZipPostalCodeEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.ZipPostalCodeEnabled" data-val-required="'Zip Postal Code Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_ZipPostalCodeRequired" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.ZipPostalCodeRequired" data-val-required="'Zip Postal Code Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_PhoneEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.PhoneEnabled" data-val-required="'Phone Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_PhoneRequired" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.PhoneRequired" data-val-required="'Phone Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_FaxEnabled" type="hidden" value="True" name="Address.FaxEnabled" data-val-required="'Fax Enabled' must not be empty." data-val="true">
<input id="Address_FaxRequired" type="hidden" value="False" name="Address.FaxRequired" data-val-required="'Fax Required' must not be empty." data-val="true">
```

** there's also a  with all the fields below this

Can somebody tell me where I can edit this javascript code? I've done a search in both Nop.Web and Nop.Admin for both cshtml and js files. I've also done search for the string "url: "/Admin/Country/GetStatesByCountryId"," to perhaps find the js code. but no luck so far.

Regards

Comment: Check in EditorTemplates folder which must be in same folder this calling view is i.e customer. Or check in shared.